# JavaFx removing child node loses functionality, but stays present

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

I have a custom component that extends CubicCurve. It is the third child of an AnchorPane;

```
Scene
    AnchorPane
        BorderPane
            Circle
               CubicCurve
```

When I call `anchorpane.getChildren().remove(cubic_curve)` it loses its functionality (the start and end points are bound to a moveable node -- these are not bound anymore), however I can still see it.

Is there a proper way to 'delete' the shape? Everything I've found just points me to removing the child, however this doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should work. If it doesn't, you probably have something else wrong somewhere. Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Just wondering, is CubicCurve a child of Circle? Shapes can't have children. I assume it's a child of the border pane so fix the indentation.

Comment: Wait, is getChildren().remove( ) recursive? I.e. searching though the entire child hierarchy? I never knew...

Comment: I found my solution - `getChildren().remove` wasn't the issue (@James_D, you were correct) @MouseEvent, the Circle was a custom component that extends Circle. Probably should have specified that!

Comment: @James_D From what I understod from the question above, he called remove on AnchorPane (child of scene) but that removed the CubicCurve (child of Circle). I thought .getChildren( ) only retrieved direct children.

Comment: @Gikkman I see what you are asking now. As @MouseEvent pointed out, the indentation is probably wrong ("it is the third child of an `AnchorPane`"). The call to remove is not recursive.

Comment: @James_D Gotcha. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I was calling `getChildren().remove(cubic_curve)` within an `.setOnMouseDragReleased()` handler. When I put it within a `.setOnMouseReleased()` handler it worked perfectly.

I was trying to connect two nodes with a cubic curve by dragging and dropping. The `onDragRelease` handler would be called by the node that is dropped upon -- the curve that it was referencing was not the correct one. By moving it to `onMouseReleased`, the handler references the first node that then references the correct curve.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Great that you report back with a solution. :) I edited you answer and added some formatting.